# x86 Assembly errors: "Error error A2008: syntax error : cqd" and "error A2008: syntax error : indiv"

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am trying to make a program work that I copied out of my textbook. I am trying to learn arrays for x86 assembly, but this example is giving me an error despite it being a copy of an example. It doesn't like the commands `cqd` and `indiv`, which the comments say "extend sum to quadword" and "calculate average" respectively. Below is my code:

---

```
;given an array of double word integers, 1.) find their average and 2.) add 10 to each number 
;smaller than average

.586    
.MODEL FLAT
.STACK 4096                 ; reserve 4096-byte stack

.DATA
nbrArray DWORD 25,47,15,50,32,95 DUP (?)
nbrElts DWORD 5

.CODE
main    PROC

; find sum and average
mov eax, 0              ; sum := 0
lea ebx,nbrArray        ; get address of nbrArray
mov ecx,nbrElts         ;count := nbrElts
jecxz quit              ;quit if no numbers
forCount1: 
    add eax, [ebx]      ;add number to sum
    add ebx,4           ;get address of next array elt
    loop forcount1      ;repeat nbrElts times
    cqd                 ;extend sum to quadword
    indiv nbrElts       ;calculate average

; add 10 to each array element below average
    lea ebx, nbrArray   ;get address of nbrArray
    mov ecx,nbrElts     ;count := nbrElts
forCount2:
    cmp [ebx], eax      ;Number < average ?
    jnl endIfSmall      ;continue if not less
    add DWORD PTR [ebx], 10 ;add 10 to number
endifSmall:
    add ebx,4           ;get address of next array elt
    loop forCount2      ;repeat
quit:
    mov eax,0       ;exit with return code 0
    ret
main ENDP
END
```

Comment: Maybe you mean `cdq` and not `cqd`. No such thing as `indiv`, maybe you mean `idiv`

Comment: In other words: if you copy from a textbook (that is soooo nineteen eighties <g>), and there is no digital version, then make sure you have no typos, especially if you don't really understand what you are copying.